# sql query based on mulitple column combination in where clause and handle 'IN' or Not In operator

Tags: sql

I need to check if a 2 column combination in table for UNIQUE Column ID in a table. Example: I have a table 
 TABLE A

```
----------------------------------
ID      TYPE          VALUE
---------------------------------
1   CUST        1
1   SOLDTO      3
1   SHIPTO      2
2   CUST        1
2   SOLDTO      2
2   SHIPTO      5
3   CUST        1
3   SOLDTO      2
3   SHIPTO      3
----------------------------------
```

I need to check condition combination

```
if ( TYPE = 'CUST' VALUE = 1 ) 
      and ( TYPE = 'SOLDTO' VALUE  IN RANGE 2 to 3 ) 
      and (TYPE = 'SHIPTO' VALUE NOT EQ 3)
```

Should Return the entry

```
2   CUST        1
2   SOLDTO      2
2   SHIPTO      5
```

Please assist.

Comment: Way 1- Pivot on id, do a normal where clause, unpivot if you need to. Way 2- put conditions as 3 case when then 1 else 0 and group by id having sum(case when's) = 3

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: If `TYPE = 'SHIPTO' VALUE NOT EQ 3` then it should return `SHIPTO      2` and `SHIPTO      5` but in your expected output it's only `SHIPTO      5` how ??

Answer (score 0):

you can try by using exists and not exists

```
select * from t where exists
                          ( select 1 from t t1 where t1.ID=t.ID 
                            and t1.TYPE in('CUST','SOLDTO') 
                            and t1.VALUE>=1 and t1.VALUE<=3)
                 and not exists ( select 1 from t t2 where t2.ID=t.ID
                                  and t2.TYPE='SHIPTO' and t2.VALUE!=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the interesting id:

```
SELECT ID FROM table 
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(
    case when (type = 'CUST' and VALUE = 1) or
      (TYPE = 'SOLDTO' and VALUE between 2 and 3) or
      (TYPE = 'SHIPTO' and VALUE <> 3)
      THEN 1 else 0 
    end
) = 3
```

If you want all the row data, join it back to the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  --put query from above inside these brackets
)
SELECT t.* FROM t INNER JOIN cte.id = t.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID  INT, [TYPE] VARCHAR(20), VALUE INT)

INSERT INTO @TableA VALUES
(1 ,'CUST  ', 1),
(1 ,'SOLDTO', 3),
(1 ,'SHIPTO', 2),
(2 ,'CUST  ', 1),
(2 ,'SOLDTO', 2),
(2 ,'SHIPTO', 5),
(3 ,'CUST  ', 1),
(3 ,'SOLDTO', 2),
(3 ,'SHIPTO', 3)

SELECT * FROM @TableA TA
WHERE 
EXISTS(
    SELECT ID FROM @TableA T
    WHERE T.ID = TA.ID
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN T.[TYPE]='CUST' AND T.VALUE = 1 THEN 1 END) = 1 
        AND   COUNT(CASE WHEN T.[TYPE]='SOLDTO' AND T.VALUE >=2 AND T.VALUE < 3 THEN 1 END) = 1 
        AND   COUNT(CASE WHEN T.[TYPE]='SHIPTO' AND T.VALUE <> 3 THEN 1 END) = 1 
)
```

Result:

```
ID          TYPE                 VALUE
----------- -------------------- -----------
2           CUST                 1
2           SOLDTO               2
2           SHIPTO               5
```